# When does the continuity of composition imply the continuity of the terms

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

If $fg$ is continuous and $g$ is topologically a regular epi then $f$ is continuous. Analogously, if $fg$ is continuous and $f$ is topologically a regular mono then $g$ should be continuous.

They are simple to prove. For example for the second one: given an open $U$ in domain of $g$, if $g^{-1} U$ was not open then neither would be $f^{-1}g^{-1} U$.

Statements like these about whether the composition of morphisms "are" in certain category are not rare in mathematics: these ones involve the category of sets and of topological spaces. But they seem a bit stranger and I'd like to understand them better conceptually. Is there some nice framework to study questions like this categorically?